# Asp.net Radiobutton display issue, black circle displays differently when selected

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

Problem is Sometime in aspx page, radiobutton displays differently, black circle bigger than other.

any help please.
[image]

Comment: please, provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Issue is visual appearance of radiobutton is different by OS, So I am checking in Windows7 and 8  and radiobutton looks different.

http://kb.siteground.com/why_does_my_website_look_different_on_different_browsers/